# how do I call a function if the image clicked is equal to its matching word? Actionscript3

Tags: actionscript-3, actionscript, click, mouseevent

When my random word appears the user has to memorise it and click the correct corresponding image to it. I'm trying to write the code that runs if the user selects the right image. I have paired my words and images in my array. I'm just unsure as how to go about calling this function.

This is what I've attempted so far, but this isn't working. I'm new to actionscript3 so excuse the lack of knowledge as I am trying to teach myself.

All help greatly appreciated!!

Comment: how do you create your images? are they just objects on a timeline with instance names?

Comment: Could you go into more detail about what you're trying to accomplish?  so you have these images,  and you can click them.   When you click one, what is happening?  what is `listAry`?    what happens on the frame `listpage`?

Comment: my images are movieclips. A random word appears on screen, this then disappears after a few seconds and 9 images appear. The user must click the same image as the word so for example the word might be - Cookies, when the pictures appear the user should click the image of cookies

Comment: I basically just want to write the code that runs a function when the correct image (that matches the word) is selected

Comment: @LDMS I edited my code above :)

Answer (score 0):

This is one way you can do this: 
See code comments

```
        basket.visible = false;

        //------ Home Button ------\\
        backhome1btn.addEventListener(MouseEvent.CLICK, goback1Click);

        function goback1Click(event:MouseEvent):void{
            gotoAndStop("homepage");
        }

        //-------------------


        var score:int = 0;

        var items:Array = new Array(); //store all food items in array
        var wordsToShow:Array = new Array(); //store all words to show in array - this is the array that will keep track of which has been asked (or rather not asked yet)

        //to reduce redundant code, call this with each food item (below)
        function initFoodItem(item:MovieClip, word:String):void {
            item.word = word; //forget the array, just store the word on the image as a dynamic property
            item.addEventListener(MouseEvent.CLICK, foodClicked);
            items.push(item); //add to array
            wordsToShow.push(item); //add to array

            item.visible = false;
        }

        initFoodItem(oc, "Orange Juice");
        initFoodItem(sand, "Sandwich");
        //...repeat for all other food items

        //now randmize the words to show array:
        wordsToShow.sort(function(a,b):int {
            return(Math.random() > .5) ? 1 : -1;
        });

        var curAnswer:MovieClip; //a var to store the current correct answer

        //this does the next question per se
        function displayWord():void {
            if(wordsToShow.length < 1){
                //they've all been asked
                gotoAndPlay("gameoverpage");
                return;
            }
            curAnswer = wordsToShow.pop(); //assigns the last item in the array to the cur asnwer, and pop also removes that item from the array (so it won't get asked again)
            randomword.text = curAnswer.word; //assign the text to the word value of this item

            randomword.visible = true;
            remember.visible = true;
        }

        remember.addEventListener(MouseEvent.CLICK, readyClick);
        //when you click your ready button
        function readyClick(e:MouseEvent):void {
            //we have an array of all items, let's loop through it and change them all to be visible
            for (var i:int = 0; i < items.length; i++) {
                //items[i].alpha = 1; //alpha values are 0 - 1 in AS3
                items[i].visible = true; //use visible instead of alpha if just toggling visibility, it's more efficient
            }

            randomword.visible = false;
            remember.visible = false;

            bask.visible = true;
            notepape.visible = false;

            //! another reason to use visible instead of alpha = 0, is alpha = 0 items will still be clickable!  visible = false items cannot be clicked.
        }

        function foodClicked(e:MouseEvent):void {
            if (e.currentTarget == curAnswer) {
                //if the current target (the item clicked) is the same item as what we stored in curAnswer, you answered correctly, so do this:
                score += 10; //or however much you get for answering correctly
                gotoAndStop("listpage"); //not sure what this does?
                displayWord();
            }else {
                //wrong
                gotoAndStop("gameoverpage");
            }
        }
```

Comment: Thanks for the help @LDMS :) unfortunately it didn't work, it didn't display the random word and I couldn't go any further, Ill keep messing around with it! Cheers

Comment: You need to be more specific than "didn't work".  Are you getting an error?  You can't just copy and paste this code,  you need to still setup your `randomword` and `remeber` buttons etc

Comment: Now, with the exception where it says `//...repeat for all other food items`, you can replace your code with mine.  If it doesn't work, it's likely because of something else you haven't included. Eg your other frames etc.

Comment: Thank you @LDMS I will have to give it a try in the morning, will get back to you with how it goes!